# Cloaking links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm looking to cloak my outgoing links in Rails, but can't find anyone doing it outside of Wordpress & PHP. I'm guessing it's either silly easy or stupidly difficult, would love clarification.

**I'm trying to achieve links to look like this:**

http://www.railsproject.com/posts/test-post

**But when clicked redirect to:**

http://www.test-webpage.com/12341/post-at-another-site

As currently my URL's look a bit ugly and SEO is hating it as well.

Any help would be grand!

**EDIT ERROR**

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column offers.friendly_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."friendly_id...
>   ^ : SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."friendly_id" IS
>   NULL LIMIT 1

```
  # GET /offers/1.json
  def show
    link = Offer.find_by!(friendly_id: params[:slug])
    redirect_to link.url
  end
```

Comment: Seems like a friendly slug with an associated link, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store the slug and outgoing URL in your database, and then match them once someone visits the link.

Assume a model named `Post` with two attributes, `friendly_id` and `url`. You can set up a route like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
get "posts/:slug", to: "posts#show"
```

And in your controller:

```
# app/controller/posts_controller.rb
def show
  link = Post.find_by!(friendly_id: params[:slug])
  redirect_to link.url
end
```

Note that the links will need to start with `http://` or `https://`, or the `redirect_to` call will fail.

Comment: I currently have friendly_id's set on the posts, would this change this code at all?

Comment: @Jonathan: If you already have a model named `Posts`, that's just as fine. Same approach still applies. :-)

Comment: @Jonathan: A `friendly_id` shouldn't change anything. Just use the `friendly_id` column. I'll updated my answer with your naming convention.

Comment: I'm getting a funky error when implementing your code, please see the edited question above with the error.